# JQuery - Hover event not firing on Hover out

Tags: jquery

I am implementing my own 'tooltip' where it creates a new div element every time you hover over it and removes it on hover out. The code below is stripped down from what I use but it shows the problem: This piece of code works perfect when a user slowly puts their mouse over and off the $('#' + fieldName) object but when you move your mouse on the object and then quickly pull it off the tooltip does not get removed. Is there a way to improve my code?

I tried implementing a system where I create all the tooltip boxes and hide them, then show them on hover, but it posed the same problem with the mouse moving quickly off the object and the hover out not firing.

```
$('#' + fieldName).hover(
    function () { /* Create new DOM element */
        /* My ajax stuff here */
        var data = 'test';
        var tooltipBox = $('<div id="' + fieldName + '_tooltip">' + data + '</div>');
        $("body").prepend(tooltipBox);
    },
    function () { /* Remove Tooltip from DOM */
        $('#' + fieldName + '_tooltip').remove();
    }
);
```

**Answer:**

With help from Robert Koritnik and sajawikio:

If you need to make tooltips on hover with AJAX calls in the hover you can do a small hack to make it work.

```
var callingAjax = false;
var removeTooltip = false;
$('#tooltip').hover(
     function() {
          callingAjax = true;
          $.post(.. {
              callingAjax = false;
              /* do stuff */
              if(removeTooltip)
                   /* code to remove tooltip */
              removeTooltip = false;
          });
     },
     function() {
          if(callingAjax) 
              removeTooltip = true;
          else
              /* code to remove tooltip */
     }
);
```

Comment: I doubt that the `mouseleave` event is not triggered. Put in an `alert("out");` before you remove the element to verify it. More likely, `fieldName` changes and therefore the element you are trying to remove is not existing. I suggest to implement the tooltip as a plugin.

Comment: @maenu: I'd rather go with `console.log`...

Comment: @maenu i put the alert(fieldName) to see if it keeps it the same, it is always set, however, it is always called as well. So the problem is that .remove(); is not working.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

### Your code works

I've put your code in a [JSFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/FUdU6/) and it works, so you must have some other problem. I can move mouse as fast over the link as possible but tooltip gets removed every single time.

I'm using Chrome. What's your *drug*?

> **Note**: The only difference between my code in the JSFiddle and yours is that I've used `append` and you've used `prepend`. I've changed that for obvious reasons. Try changing it and you'll see why. But it works in both ways.
>
> **Note 2**: Actually if you change `append` to `prepend` it actually simulates fast mouse movement, because the moment when an object is pre-pended, mouse hovers out of the link. So instead of moving the mouse as quick as possible, move the element to simulate the same behaviour.

### The actual problem

The problem is that you're executing other things in hover **before creating tooltip**. It doesn't really matter whether that's an Ajax call. It may be anything that is asynchronous so Javascript thread can execute next functions. And if that executes longer than you stay on the element, your mouse out want's to remove something that hasn't been created yet (and will be later on).

Two possible solutions:

1. Add your tooltip **first** and then execute other stuff.
2. Defer Ajax call after hover event executes.

### Warning

I would strongly suggest to **not execute** ajax code in hover event because you may fire lots and lots requests. Actually, more than browser can handle. If you must execute ajax request on hover then do it this way: hover fires and prepares a function call to be executed right after it, but that function will only issue an Ajax call if one is not being in progress already:

```
// variable outside of hover closures
var ajaxExecuting = false;

// code to put within your hover handler
setTimeout(function() {
    if (!ajaxExecuting)
    {
        ajaxExecuting = true;
        // do your AJAX stuff
    }
}, 0);
```

Comment: +1 for ajaxExcecuting - good idea - yes it would be odd for executing like 100 ajaxes at once if hovering over so many thing - very good

Answer (score 1):

Yes, there is a problem. Make speed not a factor at all - do not leave it up to chance and make sure that when you hover in, your hover out activates - and when you hover out, your hover in activates! Foolproof! This way, you don't get stuck "expanded" as you state! In other words, do the events one at a time "back and forth toggle style" instead of using persistent handlers.

(See example code in action - works well if element you use is bigger of course) - http://jsfiddle.net/4jArC/

```
var fieldName = "whatever";

function b(evt) { /* Remove Tooltip from DOM */
    $('#' + fieldName + '_tooltip').remove();
    $(evt.currentTarget).one('mouseover',a);
}

function a (evt) { /* Create new DOM element */
    /* My ajax stuff here */
    var data = 'test';
    var tooltipBox = $('<div id="' + fieldName + '_tooltip">' + data + '</div>');
    $("body").prepend(tooltipBox);
    $(evt.currentTarget).one('mouseout',b);
}

$('#' + fieldName).one('mouseover', a);
​
```

Comment: Ok so you've provided an alternative solution which I'd recommend only in extremely edge cases. **It's more important** that you're stating at the beginning *Yes there is a problem*. Do you mind explaining why and where the problem is? Because I don't see a problem... And I surely don't see an explanation of it either. :)

Comment: The problem is what *you* described yourself about your very own code! That sometimes, "when you move your mouse on the object and then quickly pull it off the tooltip does not get removed" - that can happen with your code, and you saw it happen, thats why you said so, right?

Comment: More specifically - your hover code is too asynchronous, so if your mouseout is executed before your mouseover, then you will get stuck with the tooltip on.

Comment: In my version, the following happens: Ok, when I hover in, THEN create my hover out event. Ok if I hover out THEN create the opportunity to hover back in. It guarantees that you can't get "stuck"

Comment: **Exactly** that is the problem with his code. Ajax code. but your approach is not something I'd put in production (but hey that's just me). I'd rather defer the ajax call so hover executes fast as expected and Ajax can then do whatever it needs to.

Comment: Oh my bad nvm you weren't original poster - nvm - but I do know because hwen I use OP's style code (when I first started out), I always had this problem, until I started doing it with these types of listeners. Given enough elements, and enough other factors, you will see that OP's code will behave errorneous and get "stuck" without removing the tooltip as OP pointed out.

Comment: Ajax doesnt matter in my version - As long as I hovered in, only then can I fire a hover out which may remove it. As long as I hovered out,only then can I fire hover back in. With OP's code, such guarantee is *assumed* - and the guarantee does not hold up with sufficient testing, and the tooltip WILL get stuck in production usage

Comment: Thanks so much. I feel dumb forgetting that the AJAX code delays the hover and the hover out has nothing to remove. Your code however does not fit my problem.

Comment: @sajawikio this is all of my code http://jsfiddle.net/nMnCH/ what I am trying to do is setup tooltips on all selects on my form to display the information about the part. The part is the title and the name is the unique identifier. How could I work your solution into mine if I use each?

Comment: @user1627928: I've proposed an alternative in my answer how to handle this **if you really must** in this event.